# How to deploy Delphi 10.4 SOAP Web App to IIS10

Tags: web-services, delphi, iis, windows-10

I have successfully built a standalone SOAP Server that works great.  I now want to deploy it to an IIS10 server on windows 10.  I have some across many helpful articles that helped me to add the Virtual Application, configure the Application Pool, set folder permissions and enable ISAPI and CGI.  I compiled he Service into an ISAPI DLL deployed as recommended but the only response I get back is ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE.  Does anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?  What should my URL be?  http://localhost/eFileSvr/wsdl yields the same error.

This is what I expect:
[image]

Instead I get:

[image: ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE]ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: The modern approach now is to let your Delphi app run as a web server on its own, and hook up to IIS with HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/ Since you claimed that you "built a standalone SOAP Server that works great", I think what's remaining is how to allow your server to take desired port number from IIS configuration and you have tons of examples from other languages to learn from.

Comment: Did you install the required features? (related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483350/how-do-i-enable-isapi-dlls-for-iis-10-on-windows-10)

Comment: Try to enable FRT get trace logs, or use Error Page in IIS set the site to return detailed errors to browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I did install and configure the required features listed in the article which lead me to believe there must be another issue so I created the test Echo Service and installed the ISAPI.DLL and it worked as expected. So I must be missing something like runtime packages or DLL's.  Is there a good tool/method to identify the required packages/DLL's?

Comment: Process Monitor will help you find any missing files (many times, they aren't in the path)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon